# Can't display footer (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

**Problem:**
run_overview() displays account_page-overview.php well.
The problem is that it blocks footer(), so the footer part disappears on frontend.
When I remove 'require $template;' of the run_overview(), it shows a footer part well, but doesn't show run_overview() part.
**Action I took:**
I tried changing the following code (and removed require $template;), but it doesn't display run_overview() part.

```
include locate_template('public/views/account_page-overview.php', false, false);
```

**Need Help:**
Would you please let me know if there is another method to display both run_overview() and footer()?
**PHP Code:**

```
private function run_overview(){
        /*
         * @param none
         * @return none (print html)
         */

        global $indeed_db;

        $post_overview = get_user_meta($this->uid, 'uap_overview_post', true);
        if ($post_overview && $post_overview!=-1){
            //print the post for user
            $post = get_post($post_overview);
            $data['message'] = $post->post_content;
        } else {
            //predifined message
            $data['message'] = uap_replace_constants($this->account_page_settings['uap_tab_overview_content'], $this->uid);
            $data['message'] = stripslashes($data['message']);
            $data['message'] = uap_correct_text($data['message']);
        }
        $data['title'] = $this->account_page_settings['uap_tab_overview_title'];

        $data['stats'] = $indeed_db->get_stats_for_payments($this->affiliate_id);
        $data['stats']['currency'] = get_option('uap_currency');

        $data['help_url'] = $url = add_query_arg('uap_aff_subtab', 'help', $this->account_page_base_url);
        $data['statsForLast30'] = $indeed_db->getReferralsAmountForLastDays( $this->affiliate_id, 30 );
        $data['referralsStats'] = $indeed_db->get_stats_for_reports( 'last_month', $this->affiliate_id );
        $data['referralsExtraStats'] = $indeed_db->get_referral_report_by_date( $this->affiliate_id, date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', time() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 ), date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', time() ) );
        $this->print_top_messages();

        $fullPath = UAP_PATH . 'public/views/account_page-overview.php';
        $searchFilename = 'account_page-overview.php';
        $template = apply_filters('uap_filter_on_load_template', $fullPath, $searchFilename );

        require $template;
    }

private function footer(){
            global $indeed_db;

            $data['footer_content'] = uap_replace_constants($this->account_page_settings['uap_ap_footer_msg'], $this->uid);
            $data['footer_content'] = stripslashes($data['footer_content']);

            $fullPath = UAP_PATH . 'public/views/account_page-footer.php';
            $searchFilename = 'account_page-footer.php';
            $template = apply_filters('uap_filter_on_load_template', $fullPath, $searchFilename );

            require $template;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting resp. WP debug mode. Pretty sure it will tell you that the `require` caused a fatal error, because the template path is simply wrong, and doesn't point to an actually existing file.

Comment: Hi  CBroe: Thank you for your advice. I checked php.log but it shows no related error.. Both templates shows well their path, the only problem is run_overview() keeps the footer from showing... Would you please let me know what elese can I try? Thank you.

Comment: Sure proper error reporting was enabled? Also check the page source (HTML in browser), sometimes error messages can "hide" in there so that you don't see them one the page (output in an element that was hidden, etc.)

Comment: Hi CBroe: I tested php error with a test file, it works well, and this page doesn't show any error. All other pages also show the footer well. Actually run_overview() part also shows well, it just blocks the footer...

Comment: Maybe your template output contains wrongfully nested / not properly closed HTML tags - which could make the browser not _show_ the footer, although the HTML code for it is actually present in the page source.

Comment: Hi CBroe: I see, thank you for your advice and I'll look for possibilites according to your comments, thanks again